# Why MySql doesn't use my index and how to avoid the "Using temporary; Using filesort"?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing, sql-order-by

I have a MySql query that looks like the following:

```
SELECT trace_access.Employe_Code, trace_access.Employe_Prenom, 
trace_access.Employe_Nom, , trace_access.Evenement_Date, trace_access.Evenement_Heure
FROM trace_access 
INNER JOIN emp
ON trace_access.Employe_Code = emp.Employe_CodeEmploye
LEFT JOIN user
ON emp.Employe_ID = user.Employe_ID
LEFT JOIN role 
ON role.User_ID = user.User_ID
WHERE trace_access.Employe_Nom Not Like "TEST%NU" 
ORDER BY trace_access.Evenement_Date DESC , trace_access.Evenement_Heure DESC
```

The table "trace_access"contains almost 20 million entries.

When I explain the query:

[explain query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3YLD.png)

My question is why MySql didn't use the key for the emp table and how to avoid "Using temporary; Using filesort" ??

I have tried to froce it to use my index but that didn't work.
The query lasts one hour and more, writes a file on /tmp folder that exceeds 8Go !!!

Any help ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I doubt that a condition based on NOT will use an index, even worse when it's a LIKE. But a simple Select like this should not runover an hour on only 20 million rows. How many rows are returned?

Comment: Something strange is going on.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables; I suspect an inconsistent datatype.

Comment: There is a redundant comma ',' in the query. Is this the actual query you ran?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current execution plan (to start with `emp`), a full table scan is required and there is no usefull index on `emp`. This can make sense when you only get a relatively small amount of rows after your `join` to `trace_access`, which probably isn't the case here.

To prevent the `filesort`, you need an index that supports your `order by`. So add, if it doesn't exist yet, the index `trace_access(Evenement_Date, Evenement_Heure)`.

This might already be enough to make MySQL start with `trace_access`. If not, replace `INNER JOIN emp` with `STRAIGHT_JOIN emp`. This will force MySQL to do so.

Also add an index for `emp(Employe_CodeEmploye)`.

Depending on your data, you can try to add `Employe_Code` and/or `Employe_Nom` as 3rd and/or 4th column to the index on `trace_access`, though it will probably not have much effect.